# How to calculate standardized regression coefficients with beta.glm function in r having weights in my model?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

At the moment I am running logistic regressions on individual data with weights.
Here is my model:

```
model <- glm(Dummy_WBT_17~ hinc2 + tmp_b4p_bildung_quote + benefits_7 + benefits_10 + Dummy_PartyID + gender + age_rec + region_rec + urban, weights = weight, data=new3, family=binomial)
```

In a next step I wanted to calculate standardized regression coefficients with beta glm from 'reghelper' package . But I receive the following error:

```
beta(model)
Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'weight' not found
```

There is no error if I exclude the weights from my model. So I think the error is due to using weights in my model. 
Do you have any idea how to calculate standardized regression coefficients inculding the weights?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have an object or variable in your workspace called 'weight'? The error appears to be that r is unable to find an object with that exact name. Have you checked capitalisation and plural/singular is consistent?

Comment: I checked everything. Capitalisation and plural/singular is consistent. The variable in my data 'new3' is called 'weight'. So I wonder why R claims that there is no object 'weight'. Maybe it's a more general problem, such that you can't calculate standardized coefficients if you weight your data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem seems to be a little bit strange. We tried the following:

```
test=model$model
names(test)
 [1] "Dummy_WBT_17"         
 [2] "hinc2"                
 [3] "tmp_b4p_bildung_quote"
 [4] "benefits_7"           
 [5] "benefits_10"          
 [6] "Dummy_PartyID"        
 [7] "gender"               
 [8] "age_rec"              
 [9] "region_rec"           
[10] "urban"                
[11] "(weights)"
```

It seems like the glm function renamed automatically the variable weight 
into "(weights)". That explains why beta function claims: "object 'weight' not found". Since it wasn't possible to rename "(weight)" into weights, we created a new variable which is simply a copy of "(weight)" and renamed it.

```
model$model[,12] = model$model[,11]
names(model$model)[12]="weight"
```

And now the beta function works.

```
beta(model)
```